# Create a custom shortcut that types clipboard contents

Tags: 12.10, remote-access, system-settings, xdotool

I want to simulate keyboard input so that I can "paste" my clipboard contents to applications that don't allow it (e.g. remote KVM).  Right now, I'm trying to use `xdotool` and `xclip`:

```
xdotool type "$(xclip -o)"
```

This command works if I stay in a terminal window, and type that command myself. It types back my clipboard contents when I run the command.  My goal is to bind this command to a hotkey, so that it works in any application.

[image: Linux Sendkeys]

If I use this hotkey, unexpected behavior occurs to whatever window has focus. e.g. my terminal window size shrinks (it's somewhat amusing, actually).  Similar results occur if I save it as a script and call the script, or if I encapsulate the command with `sh -c`. How can I make practical use of the powerful `xdotool type` command?

Comment: That's because the command will be run in a background terminal, you are doing nothing wrong. A terminal will "pop out" without you see it, then will execute this command, then leave.

Comment: Did you try putting it in a script and keybinding the script ? Or did you try keybinding `sh -c 'xdotool type "$(xclip -o)"'` instead ?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas @user55822. I had the same results using a script. I saw more unexpected behavior when I used `sh -c` (gedit opening new tabs). Oddly, it stopped doing anything after I tried different hotkeys.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have two problems with this command. The first is that you need to make sure that the meta-keys in the binding are not pressed when it tries to run the command.  Second, by default xclip selects `XA_Primary` buffer rather than the `XA_CLIPBOARD`.  So you should pass `clipboard` as the selection parameter for xclip. Change your hotkey command to the following:

```
sh -c 'sleep 0.5; xdotool type "$(xclip -o -selection clipboard)"'
```

Comment: This does seem to work quite reliably.

Comment: This is so useful for websites that disallow pasting passwords, thanks!

Comment: Nice ; this lead me to this script which splits the lines for multi-line pastes. The use case for this is that typing Markdown into a Google Doc formats it, but pasting just leaves it as Markdown. Bound the script to <kbd>ctrl-alt-V</kbd> and now I can edit in Vim and still get a formatted document. https://github.com/POMATu/xdotool-type-clipboard/blob/master/xdotool-type-clipboard

Answer (score 3):

xdotool creates keypresses, and it won't release the Ctrl key for you... The simplest solution is to add a delay, *eg* `sleep 0.5` to wait for half a second, and to make sure you release Ctrl fast enough.

Comment: Great idea. `xdotool type "Hello World!"` mostly works for me now. It oddly doesn't work for a few seconds after I use it, but that's not really a huge problem. The `xclip` output isn't working yet, but I'll try to figure out why.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

sh -c 'xdotool type --clearmodifiers -- "$(xclip -o -selection clipboard)"'

"--clearmodifiers" gets rid of CTRL/ALT/Shift etc, hopefully meaning the sleep is not required

"--" means end of xdotool options so that if the pasted test begins with - xdotool will not try to interpret it as an option

Comment: When I tried this, my modifier keys got "stuck" down until I pressed and released them. Also the begging of my text did not make it to the application still.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are two buffers accessible with `Ctrl+V` (the clipboard copy-paste) and `Shift+Insert` (the mouse mark and middle-click paste).

If you have the sessions appropriately connected to share clipboard, then one of the two should work automatically, no?

Comment: I need input automation because I often use remote KVM to access machines (Raritan and IPMI). Usually to install an OS or because networking is broken on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Since Unbuntu now uses Wayland, `xdotool` doesn't work by default.

I was able to modify Alex L's solution to use `ydotool`:

`sh -c 'sleep 0.5; xclip -o -selection clipboard | ydotool type --file -'`

I needed newlines to be typed as carriage returns, which wasn't available from the built in 0.1.8 ydotool, but did work great from 1.0.4 installed from sources following [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1413829/how-can-i-install-and-use-the-latest-ydotool-keyboard-automation-tool-working-o).