# How can I install and use the latest ydotool (keyboard automation tool working on Wayland) in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: software-installation, keyboard

The valuable keyboard automation tool `xdotool` does not work on Wayland. A new tool that mimicks some of the functionality of xdotool, but that works both in Xorg and Wayland, is [ydotool](https://github.com/ReimuNotMoe/ydotool).

`ydotool` is available in the Ubuntu software center as version 0.1.8-3. It the mean time, the tool has been "refactored" in the sense that it has been completely rewritten, has no external dependencies and uses a lot less memory and without dynamic memory allocation. It is therefore strongly preferred to use a current version.

Only source code is provided on github, without instructions on how to build the code and install the tool. How can we install **ydotool 1.0.1.** on Ubuntu?

Comment: In my Q&A I go over installing the latest version of `ydotool` too: [How can I write a program to press keys, such as Windows + D, in Wayland? (replace `xdotool` in Wayland)](https://askubuntu.com/a/1473061/327339)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the advent of Wayland, automation utilities like `xdotool`, which are designed for Xorg, do not anymore work. [`ydotool`](https://github.com/ReimuNotMoe/ydotool) is a keyboard automation tool that works independent of the display manager, i.e., it works on both Wayland and Xorg.

Following are installation instructions I tested on Ubuntu 22.04. Credits to [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/m1jids/question_help_installing_ydotool_for_wayland/) for the compilation instructions using cmake.

**1. Prerequisites**

1.1 Make sure you have the necessary tools for compilation.

```
# Needed for compilation
sudo apt install cmake scdoc pkg-config
```

1.2 In Debian based distributions, `checkinstall` can be used to package the compiled code into a `.deb` file instead of moving the compiled files directly into the system directories. That way, the custom compiled program is known in the package management system, and can easily be removed again if desired.

```
# For generating an installable .deb file
sudo apt install checkinstall
```

1.3 Optional: Install `git` to clone from git. Alternatively, you can download and unpack the `.zip` file from the github page.

```
# Optional: git to clone the repository instead of downloading zip
sudo apt install git
```

**2. Downloading and compiling**

2.1 Download the source code using the `git` tool.

```
git clone  https://github.com/ReimuNotMoe/ydotool
```

Alternatively, download and unpack the zip file from the github page

2.2 Compilation

```
cd ydotool ## This will be `ydotool-master` if you extracted the zip file
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
make -j `nproc`
```

**3. Installation**

Instead of a classical `sudo make install` to install the compiled files into the system directories, `checkinstall` can be used on Debian based systems. `checkinstall` creates a `.deb` file which then can be installed using the APT package manager. Thus, the package management system knows about the package, and the package can easily be removed again using the package manager.

3.1 Start the tool

```
sudo checkinstall
```

3.2 Accept the default answer on the prompt

```
The package documentation directory ./doc-pak does not exist. 
Should I create a default set of package docs?  [y]:
```

3.3 Enter a description for the package

```
Please write a description for the package.
End your description with an empty line or EOF.
>>
```

for example: `Keyboard automation utility - custom install`

3.4 Change the name of the package to something more meaningfull: on the prompt

```
This package will be built according to these values:
```

enter `2` to change the package name to e.g. `ydotool-custom`. Thus, the package will be easily recognized later, and there will be no name conflict with the Ubuntu provided package.

3.5 Again accept the default answer, `n`, on the prompt

```
Some of the files created by the installation are inside the home directory: /home

You probably don't want them to be included in the package.
Do you want me to list them?  [n]:
```

3.6 However, answer `y` on the next question

```
Should I exclude them from the package? (Saying yes is a good idea)  [n]:
```

although answering `no` and leaving these files in probably does not hurt at all.

After this, the `.deb` is created and automatically installed. It could be reinstalled later with the command `sudo apt install <path-to-debfile>`.

**4. Configuration**

4.1 `ydotool` must run a root. There are probably more modern ways to allow a user to start the utility without using `sudo`, but the old trick is to set the `suid` bit on the executable.

```
# Set the suid bit so ydotool can be run by any user
sudo chmod +s $(which ydotool)
```

4.2 With the application, a systemd service is installed. Enable and install it:

```
# Have the the newly installed service recognized, enabled and started
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable ydotool
sudo service ydotool start
```

4.3 The daemon expects the socket through which `ydotool` communicates on `/tmp/.ydotool_socket`. When run as user, `ydotool` looks for `/run/user/<uid>/.ydotool_socket`. One could make a symbolic link to `/tmp/.ydotool_socket`. Alternatively, you can set a variable `YDOTOOL_SOCKET` to indicate the socket to use.

- Open `~/.profile` in a text editor
- Add the line

  ```
  export YDOTOOL_SOCKET=/tmp/.ydotool_socket
  ```

**5. Test if it works**

5.1 Log out then back in to have the environment variable take effect.

5.2 Open a terminal and test with following command:

```
ydotool type Ubuntu
```

The letters "Ubuntu" should be typed before your prompt reappears.

Comment: Thank you for a clear and comprehensive answer! With your instructions, the `ydotoold` service doesn't automatically start when the computer is restarted. To fix this, at step 4.2, after you have created the symbolic link, instead of reloading the daemon and starting the service, you need to _enable_ the service and start it. This single command does the job: `sudo systemctl enable --now ydotool`. Thank you again.

Comment: @PaddyLandau Thans for the feedback. I will update the instructions!

Comment: I had to manually create a link to get systemd to find the service... not sure why

Comment: @Rick perhaps some "refresh" of systemd (e.g. by a system restart) is needed before a just installed service is recognized? I will check this out. -> Edit: I changed the order of the `enable` and `reload` commands: that should solve it

Comment: Edit `/lib/systemd/system/ydotool.service` and change the `ExecStart=` line to read `ExecStart=/usr/bin/ydotoold --socket-own=XXX:YYY` where XXX is the desired uid and YYY is the desired gid. If you're the only user on the system, then the `id` command tells you the uid and gid to use. Restart the `ydotool` service. Now `ydotool` works without root permissions.

Comment: @djao Thank you for this suggestion. However, this would work only if there is only one user on the system that needs to use ydotool. My approach allows to enable root-less use of ydotool for any user that wishes so.

Comment: Not true -- although the single user case is easiest, you can also use group ownership and add users to appropriate groups to enable multiple user access.

Comment: On step 4.2) `sudo systemctl enable ydotool` gives `Failed to enable unit: Unit file ydotool.service does not exist.`