# Ubuntu GUI can't take virtual keystrokes

Tags: command-line, keyboard, python, mouse, python3

I am new to ubuntu and I am trying to recreate some projects I made in Windows and I have a problem with simulated keystrokes and simulated mouse movement and clicks.

So lets say I want to do something like `pyautogui.press('a')` or an alternative without using python would be to type in the terminal `xdotool key a`, the idea is simply to simulate the press of the letter a, and what happens is that it detects the keystroke, but depending on which program I am using it doesn't take it as an input. For example if I try to run that in the normal terminal it won't show as if I pressed the letter a, but if I run the command in visual studio or sublime text it works perfectly fine. It also seems that it has problems interacting between windows, using shortcuts and simulating mouse events.

Sincerely I just want to know if it is a feature that protects the system from unwanted simulated keystrokes or it's just something I'm doing wrong, because I couldn't find any information online about the topic.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu do you expect this to work on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it does not work is because you are using the new Wayland display protocol. Tools like `xdotool` and `pyautogui` only work in Xorg.

You can [run Ubuntu on Xorg](https://askubuntu.com/a/1412418/558158). Under Wayland, a tool `ydotool` that allows to simulate keystrokes in Wayland is under developement. The version in the repository of Ubuntu 22.04 is older and does not actually work. You can, however, [compile a more recent version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1413829/how-can-i-install-the-latest-ydotool-1-0-1-keyboard-automation-tool-working-on) quite easily. I am currently not aware of the development or existence of Python libraries that would provide the functionality of `pyautogui` on Wayland.