# xdotool unable to work after the 22.04.1 LTS update

Tags: xdotool

my xdotool stopped working with the 22.04.1 LTS update . . . anyone else facing the same issue ?
Here's my command:
xdotool key F11
xdotool key alt + Tab
and many other command that uses xdotool

it worked fine before the update and now all my scripts stopped working

Comment: 22.04 uses Wayland by default so x applications don't work. Log out and log into a x session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xdotool` works with Xorg only. There is an alternate tool, `ydotool` that works at a lower level and thus functions in both Xorg an Wayland. `ydotool` does not have the window manipulation options that `xdotool` has, but supports simulating keyboard and mouse actions.

You can move to an Xorg session to continue working with `xdotool`. If you prefer to stay on Wayland, you may want to move to `ydotool` to preserve the functionality.

`ydotool` is available in the repositories of Ubuntu. However, even on 22.20, an old version is shipped that, for me, did not work. I therefore compiled it from source, and that is actually not so difficult. I documented [the procedure on Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1413829/how-can-i-install-the-latest-ydotool-1-0-1-keyboard-automation-tool-working-on) here on the site.

Note that the new version is a very slimmed down version, reduced to core functionality. The new version also requires the daemon to be running. A drawback of the new version is that symbolic key presses do not work: you explicitly have to "press" and "release" keys yourself using numerical codes. As such, simulating Alt+Tab in `ydotool` translates to:

```
ydotool key 56:1 15:1 15:0 56:0
```

(We press Alt, then Tab, then release Tab and Alt.)

Comment: thanks ! works fine now after I switch to Xorg