# What will happen if I disable wayland?

Tags: 22.04, touchpad, wayland, xdotool

One of the after-effects I've noticed is that the three-finger swipe doesn't work. Xdotool key shortcuts also don't work. I wanted to use xdotool, but I have to disable Wayland first. Is there any alternative that wouldn't impact my system significantly? What other side effects are there?

Comment: When you disable Wayland, Ubuntu will use the classic X system instead. I would say that there are many advantages with Wayland compared to X, but there are still several tools and features, that work only with X. (I use X in my main computer.)

Comment: cat /etc/gdm3/custom.conf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you disable Wayland, your system will be using the traditional display driver Xorg. For practical purposes, there is not that much difference in using Xorg instead of Wayland. Animations may be a little less smooth although this may be hardly noticeable. The most significant "regression" is that touchpad gestures are more limited.

Several tools work only with Xorg. When using Wayland, some of the functionality provided by these tools can be substituted.

**xdotool** **only** works on Xorg or, if using Wayland, with applications that run through xwayland, i.e., on an xorg instance. Some of the functionality of `xdotool`, in particular simulating keystrokes and mouse movements/clicks, is provided by `ydotool`. In fact, `ydotool` is more universal: it runs independently from the display manager, so can also be used with Xorg. The version of `ydotool` that comes with the LTS edition Ubuntu 22.04 is very outdated and does actually not work. Fortunatelly, [compiling a recent version of `ydotool`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1413829/how-can-i-install-the-latest-ydotool-1-0-1-keyboard-automation-tool-working-on) on Ubuntu is easy.

**xclip** and **xsel**, utilities that allow to copy and paste to and from the clipboard using the command line can be replaced by `wl-clipboard`. There is [a tool, `cb`](https://github.com/niedzielski/cb), that can be used universily: it is a shell script that identifies the display driver and invokes the appropriate tools. Alternatively, the [Clipboard Project](https://getclipboard.app/) is an interesting universal tool for extensive clipboard manipulation on the command line, including copying and pasting files.

**wmctrl**, a tool to manipulate windows, (focus, move to another workspace, maximize, ...), many of the functionality which is also provided by `xdotool` (but not `ydotool`) is more difficult to replace. In Gnome Shell, the extension [Run or raise](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1336/run-or-raise/) by e2rd allows to implement run or raise style shortcuts, i.e., when hitting the shortcut, an existing window is raised. If there is no existing window, the application is launched. Some extensions, like [Window Calls](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4724/window-calls/) by domandoman,  [Window Calls Extended](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4974/window-calls-extended/) by hseliger and  [Focused Window D-Bus](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5592/focused-window-d-bus/) by flexagoon expose dbus calls that allow to identify windows and manipulate them through the command line.

Answer (score 3):

I also found that echo $display prints :1 if wayland is disabled. This is a problem on my old app